# Flutter Web changes text issue

Tags: flutter, dart, text, html-rendering

When I work with **flutter web** and use the `html renderer`, some of the texts changes into a weird format (shown in the screenshot).

How can I fix it? is there any way without using the `canvas renderer`?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

When running and building apps for the web, you can choose between two different renderers. This page describes both renderers and how to choose the best one for your needs. The two renderers are:

**HTML renderer**

This renderer, which has a smaller download size than the CanvasKit renderer, uses a combination of HTML elements, CSS, Canvas elements, and SVG elements.

**CanvasKit renderer**

This renderer is fully consistent with Flutter mobile and desktop, has faster performance with higher widget density, but adds about 1.5MB in download size. [CanvasKit](https://skia.org/docs/user/modules/canvaskit/) uses WebGL to render Skia paint commands.

This flag can be used with the run or build subcommands. For example:

• Run using html renderer:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

• Run using canvaskit renderer:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```

• Build using html renderer:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

• Build using canvaskit renderer:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

To override the web renderer at runtime:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers#runtime-configuration

Reference link: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers

Comment: That is not a solution, the problem still exists in html renderer, I didn't ask about how to render on web, I wanted a solution for text appearance problem.

Comment: How can I reproduce the issue? Can I have some code snippet or something?

Comment: it is just a text being displayed

Comment: I know the Flutter web platform. I've created a responsive website in Flutter. But, I never faced such issues. See: https://i.postimg.cc/BZ21tx8m/Screenshot-2023-08-29-at-7-34-41-PM.png